# How to make clickhouse database case insensitive

Tags: clickhouse

Is there any configuration which would make fields searchable case insensitive, by default?

Comment: consider using [ILIKE](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/operators/#comparison-operators) operator.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. Is there any configuration setting any clickhouse database, like what is present in SQL server (collation property) which makes database searches case sensitive or case insensitive by default for that db?